# Snowflake Stored Procedure check if a variable is Null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to check if a variable in snowflake stored procedure is null or not. I am using snowflake scripting.

My Code:

```
  begin
     select id into :id from REQUEST where id = 1;



     if(id = null) then
         return 0;
```

Comment: Per your example, is the condition you're trying to address if there is no result set (as opposed to the value returned being NULL)?  You're specifying ID = 1 in the where clause, and then testing to see if ID is NULL ... these are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for branch construct:

```
BEGIN
  -- ...

  IF (id IS NULL) THEN
     RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
```

It is also possible to use `COALESCE` if it is just a return statement:

```
BEGIN
   -- ...

   RETURN COALESCE(id, 0);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried to cover the bases here, primarily when you have no results from the query as well as when the actual result is a NULL returned value.

```
--
-- create test table
-- 

   CREATE or replace TABLE REQUEST (id integer, val INTEGER);
    INSERT INTO REQUEST VALUES (1,1),(2,null),(3,3);

-- 
-- create test proc using SQL Script
--

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_NULLS(input integer)
returns INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS

DECLARE 
val INTEGER;
rc INTEGER;
input_id INTEGER;

BEGIN
input_id := input;

-- get the row count to determine if the query criteria produces a result

SELECT count(*) into :rc 
FROM REQUEST 
WHERE id = :input_id;

-- if empty result set, return 0.  

IF (rc = 0) then return (rc);
ELSE 

-- otherwise, return the value retrieved from the query, unless it is NULL in which case return -1

SELECT nvl(val,-1) into :val 
FROM REQUEST where id = :input_id;

return (val);

    END IF;
    
END;
 

    -- 
    -- Test examples
    --

   
    call test_nulls(1); -- Returns 1
    call test_nulls(2); -- Returns -1, since returned value is NULL
    call test_nulls(3); -- Returns 3
    call test_nulls(4); -- Returns 0, since there is no result set
```